# Widgets not rendered when building Flutter apk

Tags: flutter, build, flutter-layout

So I've been working on flutter for quite some time but recently, after i changed my laptop, I encountered a strange problem.

When i run the app in debug mode on emulator or on my physical device, it runs well
but when i build an apk(debug and release both), it fails to render some widgets.This time i have a card and I've shown some data on it but i see some grey color instead of my data

How it should appear:
[image: Working app screenshot]

How it appears on app installed from built apk:

[image: Error app screenshot]

Here's the code to card widget that has the prroblem (I've saved user's information on Globals.currentUser and passing it to profile page as User)

```
ExpandablePanel(
            collapsed: Container(
              height: 170,
              child: Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                elevation: 8,
                child: Center(
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: Table(
                      children: [
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child: Text('Name',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                            Expanded(child: Text('${widget.user.data['name']}',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                            ]
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child: Text('Country',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                            Expanded(child: Text('${widget.user.data['country']}',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                            ]
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child: Text('City',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                            Expanded(child: Text('${widget.user.data['city']}',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                            ]
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child: Text('Username',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                            Expanded(child: Text ('${widget.user.data['username']}',style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(),)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                              SizedBox(height: 8,),
                            ]
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            header: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
                child: Text("About me",style: GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),)),
          )
```

Comment: by any chance, does your about me section make calls to an external database?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you share debug log with us? You probably used column in the card and it cannot calculate how much space it can take. This is an assumption. Can you wrap the table with expanded?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing exactly that, i have a table wrapped in an expanded widget. Also, adding internet permission didn't work

Comment: Mate is there a way see logs on a a release app?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your app reads an external database to get the data it needs however you didn't add the Internet permission in your main AndroidManifest.xml file at `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.new_app">
    <!-- Add the following line
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Internet permission is added by flutter in the debug and profile manifests which are used by default when the app is running on debug mode on your emulator

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Yes, i have added internet permission but i still face this problem.Actually, after logging in, i save user's data in Globals.currentUser and on profile page, i show the same data in the card. There's another page that's behaving the same way

Comment: hmm, could you add the code for that section of your app to your question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

I'm not sure what it was but i was using table and Expanded widget together
So i removed the table and used rows wrapped in a column without the expanded and it ran well

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Listview widget inside an Expanded widget. I solved it by replacing Expanded with Container with width and height. (In some phones this error showed when debugging, but some it only showed after flutter build apk install)

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder())
```

Caused gray output but,

```
Container(
    height: height,
    width: width,
    child: ListView.builder())
```

Worked fine.